# VSCode IntelliSense disabled for Flutter classes

Tags: flutter, class, dart, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have a strange issue since I installed VSCode on my new laptop. I am programming in Flutter, and IntelliSense works just fine, except for classes autocompletion, which is kind of annoying. It just won't suggest classes, event when they are part of already imported packages, while on my previous laptop, it even suggested classes auto-import. I tried Settings Sync from my other laptop, but it just doesn't do the trick.

I tried searching and tweaking through similar questions, but I cannot seem to find the issue.

Here is a copy of my settings.json in VSCode. Thank you in advance.

```
{
"[dart]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "editor.rulers": [
        80
    ],
    "editor.selectionHighlight": false,
    "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "editor.tabCompletion": "onlySnippets",
    "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false
},
"editor.quickSuggestions": true,
"editor.suggest.localityBonus": true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was a synchronization issue in the pubspec.yaml of the project. I edited it (added and removed a blank line), saved it and ran "flutter pub get" manually.

It works fine now.